# Issue installing CodePro Analityx on STS (Kepler): menu not appearing

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, codepro

I installed CodePro via update site (http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/codepro/latest/3.6) in my STS. Installation completed correctly, but I cannot see the CodePro menu.

Further data:

Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.5.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 201405030657
Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)

Where can I start looking for the issue?

Comment: I am not aware of any general incompatibilities between STS and CodePro (and tried to install this myself a minute ago into a fresh copy of STS 3.5.1 successfully). If you would like to investigate this further you can open a Host OSGi concole (in the console view) and type "ss" for "short status" in there. It gives you a list of installed bundles and information about their state. If there is anything that is showing up as "INSTALLED", you can do a "diag <number-of-that-bundle>" to check why this specific bundle can't operate as expected. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that helped finding it was incorrectly installed. I uninstalled it, reinstalled it and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!